# Laravel how can using the require file

Tags: laravel

Laravel how can I use the require file when using @section('content') method, how can I require the file into the this?

[image: code view]

I want to using the menu bar, but I don't know how to separate it.

I have this code

```
<div class="links">
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/aboutme">About Me</a>
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/employmenthistory">Employment History</a>
            <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
            <a href="https://blog.laravel.com">Blog</a>
            <a href="https://nova.laravel.com">Nova</a>
            <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
            <a href="https://vapor.laravel.com">Vapor</a>
            <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
        </div>
```

can independent to menu.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make menu.blade.php with this code in your views directory.
2. In place of code write @include('menu')

If location of file is different then @include('path-to-file') will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel blade you can use `@include('file path')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [yield()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates) to solve the problem.